# goneMargin is not respected in a wrap_content ConstraintLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I have a `ConstraintLayout` where its height is `wrap_content`.

I want its height to be able to collapse or expanding, according to its Child's height. Simple and common enough, right?

Now I have a layout which looks like this:
[image]
(First of all, please ignore the abnormal super large margin at the bottom. As you can see, the margin is just 16dp but the preview renders a very large margin.)

My problem is, if the big rectangle's visibility is set to `gone`,
According to the documentation of `ConstraintLayout`, if I set its `goneMarginTop` to a certainValue, it will retain that margin even when its visibility is `gone`. So that my `Request Date` will have some space to the bottom of parent.

However, this does not work as expected. `Request Date` sticked to the bottom of its parent:
[image]
(This is again a broken preview. In my real app, I am able to see a complete Request Date)

Have I done something wrong? Here is my complete code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@color/colorBasicGrey"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/item_indicator"
        android:layout_width="8dp"
        android:layout_height="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/group_member_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/group_member_join_group_request"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/item_indicator"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/item_indicator"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/item_indicator"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        style="@style/general45"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/group_member_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/general45"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@id/group_member_label"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="180dp"
        tools:text="ABCDEFGHIJK"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/group_request_date_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/group_member_request_date_label"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/group_member_label"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/group_member_label"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        style="@style/general45"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/group_request_date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/general45"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@id/group_request_date_label"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="180dp"
        tools:text="28/10/2017"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/admin_button_container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/group_request_date_label"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_goneMarginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_goneMarginLeft="24dp"
        app:layout_goneMarginRight="24dp"
        app:layout_goneMarginBottom="0dp"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <!--To simplify the question, I hided elements inside this LinearLayout-->

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I wish Stackoverflow needs people to give a reason of downvoting.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Figured it out.

`goneMargin` is used to indicate the **margin to a GONE target**, instead of itself being GONE.

Therefore in fact I should put the `goneMargin` attributes in the `Request Date` instead of the large rectangle.