# How to align view using ConstraintLayout that support all different size screens?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout, constraint-layout-chains

I'm using `ConstraintLayout` to design my screen.

Here is my code that i have tried so far

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/home_bg">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/topImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:src="@drawable/splash_heading"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvAllOverResult"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="@string/allover_result"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlue"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        ads:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/topImage" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/firstCardView"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        ads:cardElevation="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tvVs"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tvVs"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/tvVs">


        <abak.tr.com.boxedverticalseekbar.BoxedVertical
            android:id="@+id/firstSeekBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            app:backgroundColor="@android:color/white"
            app:defaultImage="@drawable/ic_play"
            app:imageEnabled="true"
            app:max="100"
            app:maxImage="@drawable/ic_play"
            app:minImage="@drawable/ic_play"
            app:progressColor="@color/colorGreen"
            app:textEnabled="false"
            app:touchDisabled="false" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvOneScore"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Streak"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlue"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/firstCardView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/firstCardView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/firstCardView" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvVs"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="V/S"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlue"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/secondCardView"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        app:cardElevation="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tvVs"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tvVs"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/tvVs">

        <abak.tr.com.boxedverticalseekbar.BoxedVertical
            android:id="@+id/secondSeekBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            ads:points="50"
            app:backgroundColor="@android:color/white"
            app:defaultImage="@drawable/ic_play"
            app:imageEnabled="true"
            app:max="100"
            app:maxImage="@drawable/ic_play"
            app:minImage="@drawable/ic_play"
            app:progressColor="@color/colorGreen"
            app:textEnabled="false"
            app:touchDisabled="false" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTwoScore"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Steps"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlue"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/secondCardView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/secondCardView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/secondCardView" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvWin"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlue"
        android:text="@string/str_win"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvTwoScore" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/tvPlayGame"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_play"
        app:backgroundTint="#0b961e"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/bottomLayout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvWin" />


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <com.leinardi.android.speeddial.SpeedDialOverlayLayout
            android:id="@+id/speedDialOverlayLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#81000000"
            app:clickable_overlay="true"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

        <com.leinardi.android.speeddial.SpeedDialOverlayLayout
            android:id="@+id/speedDialOverlayLayout2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#81000000"
            app:clickable_overlay="true"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


        <com.leinardi.android.speeddial.SpeedDialView
            android:id="@+id/speedDial"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@id/mAdView"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            ads:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            ads:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/speeddial_scrolling_view_snackbar_behavior"
            app:sdExpansionMode="top"
            app:sdMainFabAnimationRotateAngle="90"
            app:sdMainFabClosedBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
            app:sdMainFabClosedSrc="@drawable/ic_settings"
            app:sdMainFabOpenedBackgroundColor="#4e4c4c"
            app:sdMainFabOpenedSrc="@drawable/ic_close"
            app:sdUseReverseAnimationOnClose="true" />

        <com.leinardi.android.speeddial.SpeedDialView
            android:id="@+id/langSpeedDial"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@id/mAdView"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            ads:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            ads:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/speeddial_scrolling_view_snackbar_behavior"
            app:sdExpansionMode="top"
            app:sdMainFabAnimationRotateAngle="90"
            app:sdMainFabClosedBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
            app:sdMainFabClosedSrc="@drawable/ic_language"
            app:sdMainFabOpenedBackgroundColor="#4e4c4c"
            app:sdMainFabOpenedSrc="@drawable/ic_close"
            app:sdUseReverseAnimationOnClose="true" />


        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/mAdView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="@string/bannerID" />

    </RelativeLayout>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I'm facing below issue using above code

- in small screen the `imageview` is hiding behind `addview`
- When i hide the `addview` the bottom `SpeedDialView` not adjusting
- How to Constraint the `SpeedDialView` that when i hide the `addview` it will work same as when `addview` is visible

issue screenshot

-[issue in large screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xmPM.jpg)

-[issue in small screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFFz2.jpg)

I have checked some SO Post

- [ConstraintLayout, when constraint dependent view is gone, the layout view behave weirdly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45080835/8112541)
- [keep the margin when the referenced view is gone in ConstraintLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46549516/8112541)
- [goneMargin is not respected in a wrap_content ConstraintLayout?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47133325/8112541)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/2386929/8112541
- [Android - Align view center to bottom of other view](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31697099/8112541)

Please check the below screen my expected output

[my expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvrze.png)

Can anybody help me create this layout using ConstraintLayout layout

If need more information please do let me know. Thanks in advance. Your efforts will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really like this question because you really showed your effort and its easy to help you when you are so clear with your intention.
**Now -** when you use ConstraintLayout and want images to be responsive what you **must not do** is give your views fixed size - because different phones got different screen size and with a fixed size the layout is just not responsive to all screens. 
**you can use guidelines in this way:**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Fragments.MenusDesign.ExpandableCategoriesMenu.ExpandableCategoriesMenu">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="Dummy text"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="V/s"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button7"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button5"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="streak"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView8"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView10"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline5"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="steps"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView9"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView10"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button3" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="setings"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline3" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:text="Ad"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline5" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.2" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.6" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/button5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/button5" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/button7"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/button7" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="Dummy text"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline3" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.8" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="Play"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button4"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView10" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView4"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:src="@tools:sample/avatars[5]" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

So... what have I really done here?
 basically - I used guidelines at some percent of the screen(for example 1 constraint at 20% and another at 30%). After that, I constrained my views to those guidelines and by doing that I can achieve 
view with the size  I want in some present relative to the screen.

Comment: hey @TamirAbutbul thanks for the reply let me check your answer i will update u after testing

Comment: I am updating my answer - there is things i forgot to mention

Comment: @Goku Ok check my updated answer - i added some more information

Comment: Ok fine  can u please add the `guideline` for top `ImageView` in your answer

Comment: @goku  What image view? I am sure that I have covered all of your views on that screen - what did I miss? Is that the blue row on the top of your screen?

Comment: the top `ImageView` like i have added in my screenshot above dummy textview

Comment: @guku Just edited my answer  - there is no need for another guideline - just constraint the imageView to the top EditText

Comment: ok fine thanks for your time and efforts let me check your updated answer

Comment: hey @TamirAbutbul you code is working fine i another doubt can u help on that

Comment: How can i set static width and height to `button5` and `button7` because i  need to display it like a bar in my screen

Comment: What do you mean by static with? can you give example?

Comment: As u seen in [my screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvrze.png)  i need to display results in % as bar as button5 and button7

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189719/discussion-between-tamir-abutbul-and-goku).

Comment: Hey buddy r  u there

Answer (score 2):

You can support different screen sizes by using Guidelines  which is basically component that inherits from android.view.View and specifically created for constraint 
with that in mind you will be able to use it's attribute percent
and here is a snippet of an example of the component

```
<android.support.constraint.Guideline
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/guideline8"
app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.9"
android:orientation="horizontal"/>
```

this means there will be a guideline at 90% of the screen and you can set your component to have top to bottom constraint of this guideline instead of the button so it doesn't have any weird behaviour and it's bottomToBottom constraint to be the parent if you want it to be fixed to the buttom of the screen ... etc

here is an example :
you will find that imageview is now having its bottom restricted to 90% of the screen regardless of what you do to the textview and same for textview as it's top is at 90% regardless of what you do in the imageview and also fixed to the parent with it's app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/home_bg">

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/guideline8"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.9"
    android:orientation="horizontal"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/topImage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:src="@drawable/splash_heading"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline8"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvAllOverResult"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="@string/allover_result"
    android:textColor="@color/colorBlue"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    ads:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline8"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Hey @HossamEldeenOnsy thanks for the quick reply  can u help how can use `Guideline` in above code i'm totally new in `ConstraintLayout`